# Regex remove last dot from string in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I have a couple of strings that end with a dot (.) at the end of the sentence which I need to remove in Yahoo Pipes.

Example:

```
example.com.
companywebsite.co.uk.
anothersite.co.
```

I've tried the following from a couple of posts here on SO but none have worked yet

```
/\.$/
```

or

```
^(.*)\\.(.*)$","$1!$2
```

Neither of these options have worked

I have tried a very simple find of

```
 .com. and replace with .com
```

and

```
 .co. to replace with .co
```

But the latter affects .com as well which is not ideal

**EDIT: Here is a visual of what my pipe looks like.**

[image]

Comment: Did you use `/\.$/` or simply `\.$` ? The latter should work. See this example: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=4380273f0827fcda6c6c1ee453fd454a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do something like this: `^(.*)\\.(.*)$","$1!$2`, then doing this should work: `"^(.+?)\.?$", $1`. This should match the first part of the URL and leave out the period at the end, should it exist.

EDIT:

As per your image, you should place this: `^(.+?)\.?$` in your *replace* field and this: `$1` in your *with* field. I do not know if you need to do any escaping, so you might have to use `^(.+?)\\.?$` instead of `^(.+?)\.?$`.

[image]

Comment: fyi: `.+?` essentially is a `.*`

Comment: @rinukkusu: no, it [isn't](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that fact. I always was under the impression that it does the exact same thing. Neat! :)

Comment: @rinukkusu: Not exactly. The `?` after a `*` or a `+` makes it non greedy, as pointed out by @Robin. What you mean, I think, is this: `(.+)?`, meaning optionally, match one or more characters, which would also match nothing, as would the `.*`.

Comment: Tried the following `"^(.+?)\.?$", $1` but this didn't work. I wonder if this is not a limitation or perhaps Pipe's Regex engine might be slightly different? I would think not...?

Comment: @SixfootJames: What about `"^(.+?)\\.?$", $1`?.

Comment: I've added an image to show what my pipe looks like with the Regex added to it. Thanks everyone

Comment: Shouldn't you put that `$1` in the "with"-field?

Comment: @SixfootJames: See my edit. You should do at rinukkusu suggests.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have added an image to your solution @npinti